# Calculate duration between two dates base on another column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I use python Pandas dataframe and would like to calculate duration on days between two dates and place them in separate column but only if Value1 and Value3 are the same.
Does someone know if it can be done?

```
Date        Value1   Value2   Value3
2023/02/05   True      1      5
2023/02/04   True      1      5
2023/02/03   False     1      5
2023/02/02   True      1      4
2023/02/01   True      1      5
```

Result should look like this

```
Date       Value  Value2   Value3 D
2023/02/05   True      1      5   1  
2023/02/04   True      1      5   3
2023/02/03   False     1      5   0
2023/02/02   True      1      4   0
2023/02/01   True      1      5   0
```

My knowlage about Pandas is limited

Answer (score 2):

Group by 'Value1' and 'Value3' columns then compute the diff between consecutive 'Date':

```
# If Date column is not already a DatetimeIndex
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

df['D'] = df.groupby(['Value1', 'Value3'])['Date'].diff(-1).fillna('0').dt.days
print(df)

# Output
        Date  Value1  Value2  Value3  D
0 2023-02-05    True       1       5  1
1 2023-02-04    True       1       5  3
2 2023-02-03   False       1       5  0
3 2023-02-02    True       1       4  0
4 2023-02-01    True       1       5  0
```